# How to animate a Custom View Right to Left and Left to Right using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have designed a view. Normally when I click on a button, this view will Show and Hide. Now I am trying to animate that View with Left to right and right to left. Below is my code but it is not working. kindly check it.

```
if(self.openedView) {
        self.openedView = false;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {() -> Void in



        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })

         shareMainView.isHidden = true;
    } else {
         self.openedView = true;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            /*done*/
        })

        shareMainView.isHidden = false;
    }
```

`shareMainView.isHidden = false;` this is my view which will be opened and hidden with the animation.

Comment: you want your view to expand from left to right and collapse from right to left?

Comment: yes. first click will show Right to Left view and then second click will hide and show Left to right animated.

Comment: Brother according to you posted code you're neither changing the frame of you `shareMainView` nor any constraint of it. So try playing with frame of constraint like for open state set some width (like 150) and for close set width to 0.0 in animation block.

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena oh ye

Comment: and don't forget to use `shareMainView.layoutIfNeeded()` at the last of code in animation block. It'll help to show the animation properly.

Comment: yes thanks @PramodKumarSaxena

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIView {
  func comingFromRight(containerView: UIView) {
    let offset = CGPoint(x: containerView.frame.maxX, y: 0)
    let x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset.x + x, y: offset.y + y)
    self.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.47, initialSpringVelocity: 3,
        options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.transform = .identity
            self.alpha = 1
    })

} }
```

You can use it like:

```
anyView.comingFromRight(containerView: anyView.superview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother according to your posted code you're neither changing the frame of your `shareMainView` nor any constraint of it. So try playing with frame of constraint like for open state set some width (like 150) and for close set width to 0.0 in animation block.

Don't forget to use `shareMainView.layoutIfNeeded()` at the last of code in animation and `shareMainView.isHidden = false` in completion block. It'll help to show the animation properly.

Answer (score 0):

In view did load :

```
shareMainView.frame = CGRectMake(_aview.frame.origin.x, _aview.frame.origin.y, 0, _aview.frame.size.height);
```

on button click :

```
if(self.openedView) {
        self.openedView = false;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {() -> Void in
        shareMainView.layoutIfNeeded()
        shareMainView.frame = CGRectMake(_aview.frame.origin.x, _aview.frame.origin.y, 200, _aview.frame.size.height);


        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })

         shareMainView.isHidden = true;
    } else {
         self.openedView = true;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
        shareMainView.layoutIfNeeded()
        shareMainView.frame = CGRectMake(_aview.frame.origin.x, _aview.frame.origin.y, 0, _aview.frame.size.height);

        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            /*done*/
        })

        shareMainView.isHidden = false;
    }
```

Width can be as much as you want to expand.For example i have user 200.In view did load it is 0 and then 200 while expanding and again 0 while collapsing.
Hope it will help.